# JavaScript array `push` with square brackets instead of parentheses - no error?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I did this by accident...

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
numbers.push[5];
```

Why wasn't there an error message?

[push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) needs parentheses, not square brackets. It was just a simple typo. I wasn't paying close enough attention to what I was doing... but why wasn't there an error message?

As far as I can tell, the numbers array wasn't modified in any way. It just did... nothing.

Comment: because that simply evaluates to `undefined` - any property (functions are just properties in javascript anyway) can have properties ...

Comment: Because it is just accessing the property named `5` on the property named `push`. There isn't a syntax error there, just a logic one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`numbers.push` is simply a function but you are attempting to find the property located at key `5` from it, which will evaluate to `undefined`.

```js
function test() {
  console.log("test");
}


// test[5] evaluates to `undefined` and does nothing
console.log(test[5]);

// We can even manually set this without messing up the function
test[5] = "foo";

// outputs "foo"
console.log(test[5]);

// outputs our expected value "test"
test();
```